# Visual Studio Code on Linux - How to run a C# application when "app.js does not exist", nor should it

Tags: c#, linux, visual-studio-code

I am running VS Code on Ubuntu 14.04. I am trying to run a C# web application which my team can run just fine in Visual Studio on Windows. The problem is that Code gives me an error message, "/app.js does not exist". No such file exists in our project, and I think I want to run it using "Startup.cs" instead, but despite trying to change the 'launch.json' file accordingly, another file that my team does not have, I still cannot get my project to run. Has anyone experienced a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

The .NET environment for Linux is currently in a pretty early state. Thus you can't do everything on Linux that you can enjoy on Windows. 
If you want to develop an ASP.NET application then you should read [this guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/runtimes/ASPnet5) on how to setup the environment to work with Visual Studio Code.

If you have a C# application that can already be compiled and run on Linux then you can

- create a script file which compiles the project and runs it afterwards
- and let this script be executed as the build task in Visual Studio Code. Here is how to do it: [How to prepare/configure development environment for C++ projects in Visual Code Editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33098442/how-to-prepare-configure-development-environment-for-c-projects-in-visual-code)

Just for your interest: You can't currently debug C# projects in Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try to open the project with Monodevelop? This is an open source IDE for C# that runs on linux. It is compatible with VS projects.
You will probably need to also install Mono (the open source .net runtime) to run Monodevelop.

You may even be able to run your web app with the Mono runtime, although it has been always a bit behind the official Microsoft .net runtime (you may get 'class not found' exceptions if your code uses libraries that are not yet implemented in the Mono runtime).