# Compiling C++ code in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, compilation, visual-studio-code

I installed the recommended C/C++ extension made by Microsoft. I wish to now fix compiling.

I know visual studio code is an editor with no inbuilt compiler, however there is little to no information as to how to achieve a task of fix the configuration to be able to compile code.

I run linux ubuntu 14.04 and have gcc compiler installed. I wish to use this to compile the code.

I've ben looking at tasks and when in debug mode when launching it takes to this file:

lanuch.json (these are launch configurations):

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "C++ Launch (GDB)",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "launchOptionType": "Local",
            "targetArchitecture": "x64",
            "program": "enter program name, for example ${workspaceRoot}/a.out",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true
        },
        {
            "name": "C++ Attach (GDB)",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "launchOptionType": "Local",
            "targetArchitecture": "x64",
            "program": "enter program name, for example ${workspaceRoot}/a.out",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "environment": [],
            "processId": "enter program's process ID",
            "externalConsole": false
        }
    ]
}
```

From here I'm lost. I don't actually know what to change here.

Also from this https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks there is an example of a task:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "gcc",
    "args": ["-Wall", "helloWorld.c", "-o", "helloWorld"],
    "problemMatcher": {
        "owner": "cpp",
        "fileLocation": ["relative", "${workspaceRoot}"],
        "pattern": {
            "regexp": "^(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
            "file": 1,
            "line": 2,
            "column": 3,
            "severity": 4,
            "message": 5
        }
    }
}
```

Again I don't know how to edit this so that it will compile my code.

I have the file start.cpp which includes my main function.

**So how does one setup visual studio code to compile code in the easiest and most automated way?**

Comment: Did you take a look here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33098442/how-to-prepare-configure-development-environment-for-c-projects-in-visual-code/33102094#33102094

Comment: Not having enough time to answer the question, hopefully this gives you the info to answer your own question:  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/10/24/building-your-c-application-with-visual-studio-code/

Answer (score 0):

Install the "Code Runner Extension" for visual studio code and your code should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Edit tasks.json file and paste this;

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
    {
        "label": "Build",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "g++ ${file} -o ${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.out & ${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.out",
        "args": [

        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
    }]
}
```